CS50SQL(2024) - PSET 3 - Meteorite Cleaning - New table "meteorites" order by year and name check50 output difference
I am having problems matching the check50 output with my code, even though it properly orders the meteorites by year and name, from my opinion. Moreover, it assigns the IDs starting with 1 from the oldest meteorite.
PSET3 Link https://cs50.harvard.edu/sql/2024/psets/3/meteorites/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "meteorites_temp";
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "meteorites";

CREATE TABLE "meteorites_temp" (
    "name" TEXT,
    "id" INTEGER,
    "nametype" TEXT,
    "class" TEXT,
    "mass" REAL,
    "discovery" TEXT,
    "year" INTEGER,
    "lat" REAL,
    "long" REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "meteorites" (
    "id" INTEGER,
    "name" TEXT,
    "class" TEXT,
    "mass" REAL,
    "discovery" TEXT,
    "year" INTEGER,
    "lat" REAL,
    "long" REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

.import --csv --skip 1 meteorites.csv meteorites_temp

UPDATE "meteorites_temp"
SET "mass" = NULL,
    "year" = NULL,
    "lat" = NULL,
    "long" = NULL
WHERE "mass" = '' OR
      "year" = '' OR
      "lat" = '' OR
      "long" = '';

UPDATE "meteorites_temp"
SET "mass" = ROUND("mass", 2),
    "lat" = ROUND("lat", 2),
    "long" = ROUND("long", 2);

DELETE FROM "meteorites_temp" WHERE "nametype" = 'Relict';

INSERT INTO "meteorites" ("name", "class", "mass", "discovery", "year", "lat", "long")
SELECT "name", "class", "mass", "discovery", "year", "lat", "long"
FROM "meteorites_temp"
ORDER BY "year", "name";

DROP TABLE "meteorites_temp";

The steps in which I have problems for pset3 meteorites are:
4.The meteorites are sorted by year, oldest to newest, and then—if any two meteorites landed in the same year—by name, in alphabetical order.
5.You’ve updated the IDs of the meteorites from meteorites.csv, according to the order specified in #4. The id of the meteorites should start at 1, beginning with the meteorite that landed in the oldest year and is the first in alphabetical order for that year.
I only have this to debug, which is what check50 outputs:
:) import.sql exists
:) import.sql runs without error
:) import.sql creates a table named "meteorites"
:) import.sql creates a table named "meteorites" with all prescribed columns
:) data from CSV has been imported
:) no empty values from CSV are present in "meteorites" table
:) all decimal values in "meteorites" table are rounded to two places
:) no meteorites of type "relict" found in "meteorites" table
:( "meteorites" table properly sorts elements and assigns IDs

Cause
expected "1, Apache Junc...", not "1, Adelaide, N..."
Expected Output:
1, Apache Junction, None
2, Asarco Mexicana, None
3, Aus, None
4, Benares (b), None
5, Cacilandia, None
Actual Output:
1, Adelaide, None
2, Aire-sur-la-Lys, None
3, Allan Hills 03541, None
4, Allan Hills 03542, None
5, Angers, None

I did this and voila it got accepted. I dont know what is wrong with it. I wrote the entire code correct, still it didnt accept :|
UPDATE "meteorites_temp" SET
    "mass" = NULLIF("mass", ''),
    "year" = NULLIF("year", ''),
    "lat" = NULLIF("lat", ''),
    "long" = NULLIF("long", '');


It's okay, mate. I've already completed the certificate. I still don't know what the problem was, but my guess is that it was just a weird bug.
